# Swift - Firebase multiple snapshots

Tags: database, swift, variables, firebase

So I need to capture the contents from different paths in my firebase database and save them into an array so that I can put them into a chart.

Is there any way I can get the `snapshot.Value` and save it into a variable that can then be accessed at a later point in the code?

This is the code which shows what I'm trying to do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    leave.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let vaiable = snapshot.value
    })

    remain.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let variableTwo = snapshot.value
    })

    undecided.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let vaiableThree = snapshot.value
    })

     let options = ["Remain", "Leave", "Undecided"]
     let results = [variable, variableTwo, variableThree]
     setChart(options, values: results)
```

But I believe that the firebase calls are made last of all, meaning that the variables are empty in the 'results' array.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Fire base calls are asynchronous calls so either you should  chain all you calls and if you want parallel then wait for all completion blocks to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've got an issue with 'scope'. A variable declared inside of a function or a callback will never be accessible from the outside of that function or callback.

One solution to your problem could be like this:

```
var results: [FIRDataSnapshot] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    leave.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.results.append(snapshot.value)
})

remain.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.results.append(snapshot.value)
})

undecided.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.results.append(snapshot.value)
})
```

But now you don't really have a way of knowing wether or not your `results` array is actually populated with any data, or if the callbacks are still to complete.

A safer, although still a bit cumbersome way to do it could be to refactor your callbacks out into seperate functions, and then when your first callback completes, it calls the function for the second callback, which then call the function for the third callback and then you can do something with your data. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to fix it another way which works for my intents and purposes but believe that this is the more correct answer.